# SDWebimage setImageWithUrl doesn't complete

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sdwebimage

I have a tableview in which i load some cells, and insert some images in. The images is downloaded with the help of SDWebImage library. There is one problem though: It seems the function to download the image is never called (or abruptet before completion), and therefore the complete method is never called on the imageView iv. It just inserts the placeholder image instead, which is a transparent png (yeah, i checked, it is there ^^).

No error is NSLogged in the if statement either.

Any ideas?

code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *myIdentifier = @"defaultcell";
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
    UIImageView *iv;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:myIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:myIdentifier];
        //build spinner
        spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
        spinner.center = CGPointMake(160, 47);
        spinner.tag = 101;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:spinner];

        //build ImageView
        iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:(CGRect){.size={80, 60}}];
        iv.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        iv.clipsToBounds = YES;
        iv.tag = 102;
        iv.frame = CGRectMake(15, 17, 80, 60);
        [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
    } else {
        spinner = (UIActivityIndicatorView*)[cell viewWithTag:101];
        iv = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:102];
    }



    [spinner startAnimating];
    //the rest goes here


    cell.textLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = YES;
    cell.imageView.hidden = YES;

    NSString *profilePicName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", [self.dbhandler getPicturesPath], [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey: @"filename"]];
    NSLog(@"%@", profilePicName);

    [iv setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePicName]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"Callback Error: %@", error);
        }
        [spinner stopAnimating];
        cell.textLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.detailTextLabel.hidden = NO;
        cell.imageView.hidden = NO;

        NSLog(@"done");
    }];


    NSString *subtitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Comments:  %@ \nPosted:        %@", [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"comments"], [[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"created_at"]];

    cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Votes:    %@",[[gallery objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"votes"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = subtitle;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: where is your URL format : -     [iv setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:profilePicName]  placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType){

Comment: The url is right there? [NSURL URLWithString:profilePicName] ? i tried to log the profilePicName string, and it is correct

Comment: how u formed the URL ?

get the value of that and place it in browser : [NSURL URLWithString:profilePicName]

Comment: Not sure i quite understand your question. The url looks like this. http://example.dk/pictures/exampleimage.jpg

Comment: I dont think the problem lies with the url. I checked the url and pasted it in a browser, and it loades the images just fine :)

Comment: Best practise is to encode url using `[NSURL URLWithString:[profilePicName stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`

Comment: But does that have something to do with my specific issue ? i just dont think so :)

Comment: oh, it seems the object, iv, is null. any ideas?

Comment: Put a debug in the complete block- validate all objects are there.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having a similar problem now, where my placeholder image is only updated to the downloaded image if I scroll to the next page and back in my UICollectionView

Comment: I had the same problem. In my case at first execution only "progress" was raised, and after the second "completion" exactly as described here https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/409
It seems in other cases completion is never raised (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/1209).